# Convert float to unorm in HLSL

Tags: graphics, floating-point, type-conversion, hlsl

I am trying to implement my own depth stencil like functionality in a pixel shader.

I have a normalised depth value, and I want to convert it to an integer in order to use the SM5 InterlockedMin() operation, like so:

```
uint d_uint = (uint)(dnorm * 4294967295);
uint d_uint_original = 0;

InterlockedMin(depthmask[c], d_uint, d_uint_original);

if (d_uint < d_uint_original) { //if true, we will have written a new depth into the mask, so write the element to the field
    field[c].x = d;
    field[c].yzw = i.n;
}
```

Where `dnorm` is the depth value.

However, `uint d_uint = (uint)(dnorm * 4294967295);` only ever evaulates to 0.

I know this because I can view the buffer in RenderDoc and see the shader only writes 0. I can also reduce the constant, to say 229496729, and it will write it correctly. If I set it to 2294967295 however it does not.

I know I am tripping over a floating point quantisation issue, but don't know how.

**What is the correct way to encode a normalised value in an integer array?**

I am aware of DX's [UNORM/SNORM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607323(v=vs.85).aspx), and maybe I need a break, but its not clear from that documentation how they should be used, specifically converting one to UINT in order to be used with the interlocked functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, since I suppose that dnorm > 0, you can also simply use

```
uint depthAsUint = asuint(dnorm);
```

since for positive float numbers, the binary representation satisfies the comparison operator .
eg :

```
asuint(0.1f) < asuint(0.5f) = true
```